iMac CPU overheating: clamping pressure and thermal paste squeezed completely out
I upgraded my 2019 4K imac’s CPU with an i9 9900T (35w supposed to run cooler), but am facing unexpected high temperatures with 100c and system freezes on AIDA64, or idling 60-70c.
I removed the heatsink to inspect. There was the typical suction keeping the CPU attached to the heatsink initially, but the CPU had only the lightest veneer of paste on the top of the IHS.
I wondered if anybody had any thoughts about this being the cause of the issue, and any things I should try?
There is a lot of downward pressure applied with a clamp at the rear of the logicboard, I did up the bolts to the extent of their travel without overdoing them. But my first thought is that the pressure is such that it has all been pushed out.
I had applied liberal amount of Arctic MX-5 paste spread across the top of the ihs with whips and peaks, (as seems to be typical by other imac users who upgrade). I plan to do a trial run by applying a pea sized or % pattern of paste on the CPU instead of spreading it (as I would typically do).  The paste had been opened for a few months, but I have some new unopened tubes so can try a new batch in case consistency is thicker.
Another issue is that I should have used thermal pads on VRAM instead of just MX4 paste as there is too much gap - got some pads on order (not sure if this would cause the CPU to report high temps on core though).



just so we've cleared out the painfully obvious stuff - how did you clean it before repasting it?

That appears to be an AIO cooler I wasn’t aware that Apple used AIO. Is that an aftermarket upgrade?

I think if the thermal paste gets pushed out then it was too much. Direct contact would be the best, but the surfaces of the CPU and the cooler are not perfectly even. So the purpose of the thermal paste is to fill areas where you might have air. Not more. Thermal paste conducts the heat worse than direct contact. See also https://www.corsair.com/us/en/explorer/diy-builder/cpu-coolers/how-much-thermal-paste-should-i-use/

That's a HUGE amount of thermal paste. There is SUPPOSED to be a lot of pressure, but it is supposed to be generally evenly distributed, across the CPU thermal cover. Thermal paste is only supposed to fill those gaps that would otherwise be filled with air between the surface of the CPU die and the cooler cover. Thermal paste conducts heat better than air, but direct contact conducts heat better than thermal paste. I can't really speak to other issues as I am unfamiliar with this device's default cooling setup, but on any computer that much thermal paste is its own problem. Clean and redo.

There should only be super thin layer of thermal paste.  Its just supposed to fill in any voids on the surface of the CPU so there is as much contact as possible.  If the paste is squeezing out the edges, you put too much in.

@Ramhound Apple uses heat pipes on their iMacs to keep them thin.

Its not an AIO. I think its a heat pipe type dealie https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/iMac+Intel+21.5-Inch+Retina+4K+Display+2019+Heat+Sink+Replacement/136308 see around step 66

@JourneymanGeek cleaned with IPA

Did some follow-up tests with an amount of paste on the CPU that I would typically use, the size of a petit pois, and minimal squeezing out of the sides but the paste on top still impercetably thin - as others have said maybe this is not the problem as it shows good metal to metal contact. The machine came with either i3, i5 or i7; i9 a bit of a gamble but considered i9-9900t having lower TDP might pay off, and i9 supported in 27" version of same machine from year, but I'm not sure of the mac's ability to effectively throttle down the chip and maybe this is also cause

Having an i9 in the same model doesn't mean they didn't use a different heatpipe architecture for that. Apple is famous for engineering to precise minimums.

Edit: After giving it some more thought...
Did you plug the fan in?
Your symptoms sound quite similar to me not plugging in my water pump.

Edit: I falsely assumed that was a water-cooler block.
After reviewing this YouTube video I can confidently say the CPU cooler looks woefully inadequate for a desktop. I've seen better cooling on laptops.
Additionally, the host had no business applying thermal paste to the VRM; holy crikes. They just "felt" like doing it?
Apple likes to design products purpose-built to what they sold you so if you had a i3 before the upgrade then your cooler is adequate for exactly an i3.
Based on the comments in the video, it is highly likely that your former CPU was hitting high temps as well.

Original answer:
TL;DR
Is your water-cooling pump plugged in and running?
Additionally, is it filled with water and not air-locked?
Long answer:
I had this same issue with an AIO cooler after re-applying thermal paste.
It was an i7-8700 and was hitting 60-70°C in the BIOS alone. When trying to use Windows it would hit 100°C with severe thermal throttling. I used it for about an hour before realizing the issue.
Thank goodness modern CPUs don't just cook themselves!
Anyways, my issue was that the pump was not plugged in. It was quite deceptive because the radiator fans were plugged in and spinning.
Tangentially, that is wayyyy too much thermal paste; albeit it's not the source of your issue. Apply a pea-sized dot of high-quality paste and you're good.
And yes, use thermal pads in the locations which originally had thermal pads.
